# pages:reset error gulp.run() has been deprecated. Use task dependencies or gulp.watch task triggering instead

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

As delivered, Foundation for sites 6 CLI generates an error when the gulp task pages:reset is called.  This happens anytime you edit files down in src/layouts or src/partials.

Apparently, gulp.run() has been deprecated.

Using run-sequence repairs the problem.

Around line 80 of gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('pages:reset', function(cb) {
  panini.refresh();
  //gulp.run('pages');
  sequence('pages',cb);
  browser.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. I had to do it a little differently in order to ensure the change and copy happens before the browser reload.

```
gulp.task('pages:reset', function(cb) {
  panini.refresh();
 // gulp.run('pages', cb);
  sequence('pages', function(){
    cb();
    browser.reload(); 
  });
});
```